# Самый быстрый способ копирования большого вектора

Tags: c++, оптимизация, c++11, vector, копирование

Есть большой вектор `std::vector<unsigned char> Source` на 134217728 элементов

И есть пустой `std::vector<unsigned char> Copy;`

Как быстрее всего и без большого (более 64 Mb) дополнительного расхода памяти скопировать `Source` в `Copy`?

Спасибо!

Comment: если source можно изменять то используйте `Source.swap(Copy)` это вобще за константу будет работать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Написать `vector<unsigned char> Copy = Source;` - это будет реально самый быстрый способ :)

Если очень хочется руками...

```
vector<unsigned char> Copy;
Copy.resize(Source.size());
memcpy(Copy.data(),Source.data(),sizeof(unsigned char)*Source.size());
```

Примерно так. Но этот способ годится не для любых типов, но для POD - сработает.

Comment: а разница в скорости/памяти будет?

Comment: Вам же именно *копировать*? То есть - иметь 2 вектора, с разной памятью. Эта память и будет использована... Разницу - ну, можно написать программку и посмотреть на быстродействие, теоретически делать какие-то предположения - это нарываться на неприятности...

Comment: написал программку - разница 2.1 - 2.6% в пользу `=`, но проводил немного грязно, так что хз

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: P.S. да, именно копировать

Comment: Ну, у меня такой разницы не вышло. Как сравнивал - смотрите тут: https://ideone.com/bE3ruX Но еще раз - не для POD этот метод применять нельзя.

Comment: ок, огромное спасибо! Я на свое компе прогонял, но у меня еще куча задач на нем выполняется (музыка, chrome и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Я немного не согласен с `Harry` в данном случаи. Во первых разберемся что делает `Copy.resize(Source.size());`

1. вызывается `vector::size()`
2. чтобы распределить память для такого количества элементов,
3. инициализировав их значением по умолчанию
   Дальше  `memcpy` копирует все элементы одного вектора в другой, заодно получая указатели на массив (Copy.data() и Source.data()).

Теперь рассмотрим что делает копирующий конструктор вектора. 
Этому конструктору известен размер, и ничего не нужно вызывать(хоть и `vector::size()` встроенная функция, но все же). Если вектор пустой, копирующий конструктор создает  неинициализированную область памяти(т.е. нет никаких элементов, а захвачены последовательности байтов) и инициализирует эти поля значениями из элементов другого вектора. Т.е. копирование происходит максимально быстро(быстрее не напишете  ни руками, ни другими средствами). И вот доказательство:

```
class Timer {
    using T = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
    T t1, t2;
public:
    void start() { t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
    void stop() {
        t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << '\n' << (t2 - t1).count() << '\n';
    }
};
int main() {  
    std::vector<unsigned char> Source(134217728, 1), Copy;
    Timer t1, t2, t3;
    t1.start();
    vector Copy1 = Source;
    t1.stop();
    // 80249486      

    t2.start();
    Copy.resize(Source.size());
    memcpy(Copy.data(), Source.data(), sizeof(unsigned char) * Source.size());
    t2.stop();
    // 88608380
    return 0;
}
```

Вообше   `std::vector`  написан очень тщательно, и там не найти место,  где можно оптимизировать. Единственное, что вы можете сделать, это просто считать копируемый вектор более не нужным и перемещать данные(move конструктор) или менять местами представления векторов  применяя `std::swap`. Так что, даже при том, что  `memcpy` выполняет быстрое копирование, и ответ от `Harry` является полезным и достоен внимания, я не согласен, что этот способ быстрее.

Можно еще использовать `std::array` вместо вектора, если удобно использовать его в вашей программе(не всегда же вектор нужно использовать), и тогда копирование будет таким же быстрым, как и для обычных массивов.

Comment: А если поменять местами в программе memcpy и Copy1 = Source ? Только запускайте каждую версию раз 10. У меня получилось, что первый  в большей части запусков немного быстрее (почему так, достоверно не знаю).

Comment: @avp,  Операционной система работает, и во время измерений погрешности будут, но все же копирующий конструктор вектора  сразу инициализирует значениями  элементов копируемого вектора и не может быть медленнее(кстати,, в ответе я допустил грамматическую ошибку, но теперь исправил. Спасибо за ваш коммент, а то я не заметил бы)

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что vector  медленнее. Скорее всего скорость одинакова. Я пишу о том, что у меня vector перед memcpy немного быстрее, а после -- немного медленней. Это видно, если запустить программу раз 10. Вы такие замеры у себя еще не проводили?

Comment: @avp, да, я понел вас, и при замерах часто сам наблюдал, что разница такая есть. Если например написать простой цикл с постинкрементом и преинкрементом, то разница по времен опять же будет зависеть что первым напишешь. Думаю это связано и с оптимизацией от компилятора.